# How to ban adding elements into <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question about adding element into the table. I have a table, to which pictures are added randomly. But in some moment two pictures added into one  tag. How can I ban adding the picture, if  contains one?

```
function randomBlock()
{
   var apple = '<img class="applepic" id="applepic" src="Assets/Apple.png" style="width:100%; 
   height:100% position:absolute; z-index:20">'

   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
   var randomTd1 = $('#clickabletable td').eq(randomNum);
   randomTd1.append(apple);
 };

 function randomSecondBlock()
 {
   var apples = document.getElementsByClassName("applepic");
   for(i=0; i<apples.length;i++)
   {
      apples[i].remove();
   }

   var tomatoes = document.getElementsByClassName("tomatopic");
   for(i = 0; i<tomatoes.length;i++)
   {
      tomatoes[i].remove();
   }

   var tomato = '<img class="tomatopic" src="Assets/Cherry.jpg" style="width:100%; height:100% 
   position:absolute; z-index:5;">'
   var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
   var randomTd2 = $('#clickabletable td').eq(randomNum);
   randomTd2.append(tomato);
   };

 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   var func = function()
   {
      randomSecondBlock();
      randomBlock();
      var time = 1000;
      setTimeout(func,time);
   }
   func();
```

Comment: Check the `<td>` element's `.innerHTML` string to see if it contains `<img>` before adding a new image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
if( !randomTd2.find(‘img’) ){//add image code}
```